# Rust and plotters library - hard to specify types of variables and refactor code into functions

Tags: rust, types, borrow-checker

This code draws four red dots in a picture.

```
﻿﻿﻿use plotters::chart::{DualCoordChartContext, ChartContext, SeriesAnno};
use plotters::coord::types::RangedCoordf32;
use plotters::prelude::*;
use plotters::coord::Shift;

type CC<'a> = ChartContext<'a, BitMapBackend<'a>, Cartesian2d<RangedCoordf32, RangedCoordf32>>;
//type CCBAD = ChartContext<BitMapBackend, Cartesian2d<RangedCoordf32, RangedCoordf32>>;
const OUT_FILE_NAME: &'static str = "sample.png";

pub fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let root_area: DrawingArea<BitMapBackend, Shift> =
        BitMapBackend::new(OUT_FILE_NAME, (400, 400)).into_drawing_area();
    let mut cb: ChartBuilder<BitMapBackend> =
        ChartBuilder::on(&root_area);
    let mut cc: ChartContext<BitMapBackend, Cartesian2d<RangedCoordf32, RangedCoordf32>> =
        cb.build_cartesian_2d(0.0f32..5.0f32, 0.0f32..5.0f32)?;
    let series: Vec<f32> = vec![1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0];
    cc.draw_series(PointSeries::of_element(
        series.iter().map(|x| (*x, *x)), 3,ShapeStyle::from(&RED).filled(),
        &|coord, size, style| { EmptyElement::at(coord) + Circle::new((0, 0), size, style) },
    ))?;
    Ok(())
}
```

I put the explicit types of variables on purpose (because why not?).
Soo... the types seem a bit long. How about we make shorter names.
Let's start with ChartContext. The compiler only lets me make the type `type CC<'a>`. `CCBAD` has missing lifetimes.
But if I try to use it like this:

```
    let mut cc: CC = // ChartContext<BitMapBackend, Cartesian2d<RangedCoordf32, RangedCoordf32>> =
        cb.build_cartesian_2d(0.0f32..5.0f32, 0.0f32..5.0f32)?;
```

It's suddenly a problem! Why?

```
16 |         ChartBuilder::on(&root_area);
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
25 | }
   | -
   | |
   | `root_area` dropped here while still borrowed
   | borrow might be used here, when `root_area` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `plotters::drawing::DrawingArea<plotters::prelude::BitMapBackend<'_>, Shift>`
```

Another story is trying to put the "draw_series" call into a function. Basically it ends up with the same error message as here.
Why I can specify the type `ChartContext<BitMapBackend, Cartesian2d<RangedCoordf32, RangedCoordf32>>` but cannot make a 'type' definition with it. Why that weird error?

Comment: We don't usually specify types because largely they are redundant and only add noise. By creating your custom type definitions you make your code even harder to understand since in addition to the original types a reader now has to read your custom type definitions too. Also writing the exact type makes refactoring harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reusing the same lifetime twice you're forcing 2 lifetimes to be the same that shouldn't be.
Use this instead:

```rust
type CC<'a, 'b> = ChartContext<'a, BitMapBackend<'b>, Cartesian2d<RangedCoordf32, RangedCoordf32>>;
```

Comment: If lifetime is part of type, why I could write that with no lifetimes? Are they implied? This statement moves the ownership.
let mut cc: ChartContext<BitMapBackend, Cartesian2d<RangedCoordf32, RangedCoordf32>>

Comment: Because in the function all lifetimes can easily derived from the usage. In the type definition there is no context from which the compiler could infer the lifetimes or their relation thus you have to specify it.